# MongoDB Text Search on Multiple and Correlated Fields Don't Return Consistent Results

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

I'm currently trying to do a text search on multiple fields of a MongoDB collection using a text index. Below, you can find the details about the collection and the index.

This is my first question ever on stackoverflow, so please be patient if details are too verbose or missing something .

##### Collection Structure

```js
db.getCollection("MyColl").insertMany([
    {
        text: "bread", 
        language: "en", 
        keywords: ["food"], 
        tags: ["foods"], 
        text_translations: {
            "tr": "ekmek"
        }
    },
    {
        text: "ekmek", 
        language: "tr", 
        keywords: ["baking", "foods", "link"], 
        tags: ["foods", "link"], 
        text_translations: {
            "en": "bread"
        }
    },
])
```

##### Index

```js
db.getCollection("MyColl").createIndex(
{
    "text_translations.tr": "text",
    "text_translations.en": "text",
    text: "text",
    keywords: "text",
    tags: "text"
},
{
    name: "MyIndex",
    weights: {
        "text_translations.tr": 30,
        "text_translations.en": 30,
        text: 20,
        keywords: 14,
        tags: 14
    }
})
```

#### Queries and Results

##### Query 1

```js
db.getCollection("MyColl").find({
    $text: {
        $search: "ekmek"
    }
})
```

This query returns both documents, as expected.

##### Query 2

```js
db.getCollection("MyColl").find({
    $text: {
        $search: "bread"
    }
})
```

But this query returns only the document with `text="bread"`, not the other one.

#### My Question

Why could this be happening and how can we fix it? Me and my teammates literally see no reason why query 2 doesn't return both documents.

We have tried to:

- shrink the index key fields down to only the `text_translations.*` ones
- use wildcard text index
- play around with weights option of the index

but to no avail. When `"ekmek"` is queried, the relation to `"bread"` is used, but not the other way around.

#### System Information

- Single-instance MongoDB running on Kubernetes
- Version: `4.1.13`